# JSON is not serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am working with a web-service and the python requests module.  I am receiving the error my file is not serializable.

My error is; 
TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

My json file is local which contains the data that I am requesting.

```
import requests

from json import JSONEncoder
import json


f = open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myla311.json', 'r')


url = "myURL"
headers = {'Content-type': 'raw', 'Accept': '/'}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.load(f), headers=headers)

f.close()

print response.text


print response
```

My expected output

```
 {
    "MetaData": {},
    "RequestSpecificDetail": {
        "ParentSRNumberForLink": ""
    },
    "SRData": {
        "Anonymous": "Y",
        "Assignee": "",
        "CreatedByUserLogin": "",
        "CustomerAccessNumber": "",
        "LADWPAccountNo": "",
        "Language": "English",
        "ListOfLa311GisLayer": {},
        "ListOfLa311ServiceRequestNotes": {
            "La311ServiceRequestNotes": [
                {
                    "Comment": "hxhdudi",
                    "CommentType": "Feedback",
                    "FeedbackSRType": "Weed Abatement for Pvt Parcels",
                    "IsSrNoAvailable": "N"
                },
                {
                    "Comment": "",
                    "CommentType": "External",
                    "CreatedByUser": "",
                    "IsSrNoAvailable": "N"
                }
            ]
        },
        "LoginUser": "",
        "MobilOS": "Android",
        "NewContactEmail": "",
        "NewContactFirstName": "",
        "NewContactLastName": "",
        "NewContactPhone": "",
        "Owner": "Other",
        "ParentSRNumber": "",
        "Priority": "Normal",
        "SRCommunityPoliceStation": "RAMPART",
        "SRType": "Feedback",
        "ServiceDate": "01/22/2015",
        "Source": "Mobile App",
        "Status": "Open",
        "UpdatedByUserLogin": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why are you importing `json` **three times**??

Comment: @ForceBru: just to be sure?

Comment: You can never have enough `json`s

Comment: @runDOSrun, yeah. We need **more** `json`'s!

Comment: you're loading a json file, which is basically just a string, then trying to dump that string?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) you need, not `json.dumps`, in order to read a json structure from a file.

```
data = json.load(f)
```

Also, it might help throwing in a few more `import json`s ;)